# What is next after a baby bouncing chair?

Tags: toddler, age-appropriate

(UK) My girl is 11 months old and is now too big for her baby bouncer chair, which she really loves and it is convenient to put her in to keep her out of the way for a bit.

What comes next? Is there a larger baby bouncer for a 1-2 year old? Is there something else on the market? I think a larger bouncing chair would be ideal for her rather than just surrounding her with pillows.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. She seems so happy in her current bouncy chair I don't like to take it away from her without a replacement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At that age you can have a good play mat or floor surface and have toys on the floor. A baby that age doesn't want to be cooped up in a bouncer/exersaucer-like thing.

Comment: I agree with @RachelS on this, what is next is nothing. Your baby is going to want to learn to walk, so will start cruising. Baby proof your house and get a stairgate or two.

Answer (score 5):

Your youngster is likely to be crawling/walking soon if not already. She will need to develop the appropriate musculature and balance.

Some parents switch to a baby play pen at this point, and others baby-proof their homes and let their kid have at it. Either way, be sure to lock your doors with bolts at this age, as my son in particular always wanted to follow daddy to work and will not know any better.

Specifically to your question, there are some models of chairs attached to tables, kind of like a low highchair with wheels that slides across the floor. But nothing I know of that bounces. My son was a bouncer, and we looked for something when he was around 10 months old, didn't find anything, and then were amazed how quickly he could crawl as soon as he was given opportunity all day. (We were not play pen people.)

Comment: I think you're referring to walkers. They are not very safe. https://www.healthychildren.org/English/safety-prevention/at-home/Pages/Baby-Walkers-A-Dangerous-Choice.aspx

Comment: No, and I believe bouncy chairs are on the banned new-sales list in the US for safety reasons. However, there are those harnesses that will hang from a bar or doorway moulding, but above a certain weight, you'll do damage to the moulding. We didn't find anything rated above 20 pounds.